# How to prove equation (7)(8) in paper A Review of the Gumbel-max Trick and its Extensions for Discrete Stochasticity in Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, mathematics

I couldn't derive the formula (7)(8) in paper
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2110.01515.pdf

They didn't seem obvious to me.